# Django - receiving multiple varities of json objects in the same post method

Tags: json, django, python-2.7

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from .models import QandA
from .serializers import QandASerializer
import json
import random
from itertools import count

class QandAlist(APIView):
    _ids = count(0)
    def __init__(self):
            self.id = next(self._ids)
    def get(self, request):
        questions = QandA.objects.all()
        serializer = QandASerializer(questions, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    def post(self, request):
        serializer = QandASerializer(data=request.data)
            if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            try:
                n = json.loads(request.body)
                return Response(n)
            except:
                return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
            else:
                questions = QandA.objects.order_by('?')[:n] 
                serializer = QandASerializer(questions, many=True)
                return Response(serializer.data)
```

here i am trying to accept 2 kinds of json. one at a time
one which updates the database with a QandA object
other which looks like
{ "number" : 3 }
this number must be extracted and 3 random QandA objects must be returned

everything except for the "number" thing works.
the try block always fails and i get exception saying i have missed all fields of QandA object

Serializer.py file is

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import QandA

class QandASerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = QandA
        fields = ('question', 'answer', 'option_a', 'option_b', 'option_c')
```

Comment: I think you want to be looking at request.DATA, not request.body.

Comment: Might also be helpful to post the definition of QandASerializer.

Comment: i added the serializer file.

Comment: What's the exact error message you're getting?

Comment: {"answer":["This field is required."],"option_b":["This field is required."],"option_a":["This field is required."],"question":["This field is required."],"option_c":["This field is required."]}    this is what is returned

Comment: i am using postman REST client and sending raw json

Comment: @perfect5th please tell me where my code is going wrong cause i have done that thing in the reverse order. First i check for the QandA object then for the number. I dont understand where i went wrong

Comment: Take a look at your logic in `def post(self, request):`. You have an `if` with two `else` blocks (I think, your indentation appears to be wrong). The second `else` will never run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, a couple of things.

First, your `QandASerializer` does not have a `number` field, which is the one you are trying to POST. It also has a bunch of fields required for the serializer to be valid.

You could just not use a serializer if you receive POST data with a 'number' in it.

```
def post(self, request):
    number = request.data.get('number')
    if number:
        # grab those random QandA objects and return them
        questions = QandA.objects.order_by('?')[:int(number)] 
        serializer = QandASerializer(questions, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    else:
        serializer = QandASerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    else:
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

You may want to add additional checks to ensure that `number` is actually a number.

Comment: Realized that you don't want to create a QandA object using your `number`, so I've removed that part of my answer.